# set Firebase path error with Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know why the error comes out today, but it was working yesterday.

```
func queryAUser() {
    let docRef = self.db.collection("Users").document(userID).collection("userdata").document("userdata")
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let aUser = DBData.Usersdata(aDoc: document)
            self.local_userdata = aUser
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: error picture]
I can't solve this error with some article in stackoverflow?

Can someone help me to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include your code as text in your question and do not post a screenshot of it. This makes it easier for others to copy the code and to reproduce the problem. Also, the link to the image might become invalid after some time.

Comment: How is your userID field defined? If you write `print(userID)` at the start of the function what does it print in your debugger? The same applies to your `db` field?